# Cast a property of objects inside an array MongoDB (string to int)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to cast a property inside an object, taking into account that this object is inside an array of objects. The array `image_list` is a property of a document.

- I need to convert `size` property from string to int
- I also need to delete `id` property

What I have

```
{ 
  ...
  other_property: "foo",
  image_list: [
    {
       id:"fooid",
       name:"fooname",
       bucket:"foobucket",
       path:"foopath",
       size:"322300"
    },
    ...more images
  ]
  other_property2: "foo2",
  ...
}
```

What I need

```
{ 
  ...
  other_property: "foo",
  image_list: [
    {
       name:"fooname",
       bucket:"foobucket",
       path:"foopath",
       size:322300
    },
    ...more images
  ]
  other_property2: "foo2",
  ...
}
```

What I tried so far

- Since I need to do it only on documents where that `size` is string, I tried this:

  ```
  db.collection.update(   
   {image_list:{$exists:true},"image_list.size":{$type:"string"}},   
   [{$set: {"image_list.$.size": {$toInt: "image_list.$.size"}}}]  
  )
  ```

Error log:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16410,
        "errmsg" : "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update with aggregation pipeline will not support projection `$` operator for array update,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `image_list` array
- `$toInt` convert `size` field to integer
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current image object with update `size` field
- `$unset` to remove `id` field form `image_list`

```
db.collection.update({
  image_list: { $exists: true },
  "image_list.size": { $type: "string" }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      image_list: {
        $map: {
          input: "$image_list",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              { size: { $toInt: "$$this.size" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "image_list.id" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/unuWKbjrRm_)